# Service / platform to work with MS Word api

Tags: api, ms-word, cloud, ms-office

I want' to organize generation reports in `*.docx` format using MS Word api. But I can't find any service which allow work with that api ( First I hope find it in office365 but I didn't ).

There are list of api's for js/python etc.
http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office

Or possible you can share experience how to organize such tasks. 
In general we use *nix stack, so cloud solution is the best variant.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, only Excel provides [such an API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer) (currently in beta).

You could generate a .docx directly but it fair warning, this can be non-trivial to get set up. Technically a .docx uses [OOXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats) which is just a zipped collection of xml files.

Comment: There are list of API's http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office I need place where I can use it

Comment: Those are the Add-in APIs. They run within Word, Excel, etc. and requires a live user. Based on your question I assume you are looking to programmatically generate the documents on a server?

Comment: Right. I understand that I need MS Word to work with it's api. I just looking for service which provide ready infrastructure to do it

Comment: I'm not saying you need Word, I am saying you need a human being at the keyboard to start the add-in for each doc. The scenario you are describing is not supported by add-ins.